# Where can I ask a question about why my freezer is creating a bunch of ice and snow?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a [Whirlpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_Corporation#1950s_to_1980s:_Early_acquisitions) refrigerator. When I bought the house, the owner that left the refrigerator told me she was removing the ice at the bottom of the freezer every 3-4 weeks. That's what I did until last week. Now I need to remove the ice every 2 days and the freezer makes a bunch of snow on my products. I tried to remove and clean the little thing behind the freezer where the "water" evacuates. It was full of dirt, but it didn't change anything.

I'm trying to find a community that can help me troubleshoot my issue, before I call a repairman or buy a new appliance.

Is there a website where that question can be answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Home Improvement / DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) has quite a few questions about [refrigerators](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigerator) and [freezers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freezing). Your question likely qualifies as

> - Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.

which is [on topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) according to their Help Center. But try to [search](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search) first before asking. Your question might already be answered.

Oh, that Help Center page recommends to add

> - **Pictures.** They really can be worth a thousand words.

in case you decide to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, that stack description, made me not post here. but I will try. Thank you.